# In SQL 2008 R2, check data of two different columns exist on same row

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I am facing following problem.

Suppose there are two tables named as `ItemMaster` `ByProduct` and `UOMConversion` and its columns like

```
ITEMMASTER:-        

    Id(GUId) Code(VARCHAR) Name(VARCHAR) ItemUOM(GUId)

ByProduct:-

    Id(GUId) Name(VARCHAR) Desc(VARCHAR) BPUOM(GUId)

UOMConversion:-

    Id(GUId) FromVal(DECIMAL) FromUOM(GUID) ToVal(DECIMAL) ToUOM(GUId)
```

So Now I want to check GUID of column `ItemUOM` of table `ItemMaster` and GUID of column 'BPUOM' of table `ByProduct` should exist on same row in  `UOMCoversion` table in column `FromUOM` and `ToUOM` or vice versa.

I am not getting how should I build this query, if anyone has done this before kindly help me to solve my problem..

Comment: If you add sample table data and expected result, it will be easier to understand the question. (I suppose it's a JOIN you're looking for.) What have you tried? Show us your current query and tell us what's wrong with it.

Comment: @jarlh: yes I am looking for a join but I haven't created any query yet. I am not getting how and from where should I start...